# What blocks can endermen pickup?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

The title says it all: What blocks can endermen pickup? I don't know what they can pickup. I know that when they were added, they could pick up anything, but now I know they can only pick up some blocks. What I want to know is what should I use in my house. I don't want endermen picking up my house's blocks. What shouldn't I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [unofficial wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enderman):

> - Grass Block
> - (Coarse) Dirt
> - Mycelium
> - (Red) Sand
> - Gravel
> - Clay
> - Podzol
> - Dandelion
> - Poppy
> - Blue Orchid
> - Allium
> - Azure Bluet
> - Orange/White/Pink Tulip
> - Oxeye Daisy
> - Brown/Red Mushroom
> - Cactus
> - TNT
> - Pumpkin
> - Melone

ProTipp: Search for everything on the Wiki. It's faster than asking here.

Comment: I was going to search on the wiki, but I was in school and it's blocked on the school's internet.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enderman#Moving_blocks), Endermen can pick up the following blocks:

- Grass Block
- Dirt
- Coarse Dirt
- Mycelium
- Sand
- Red Sand
- Gravel
- Clay
- Podzol
- Dandelion
- Poppy
- Blue Orchid
- Allium
- Azure Bluet
- Red Tulip
- Orange Tulip
- White Tulip
- Pink Tulip
- Oxeye Daisy
- Brown Mushroom
- Red Mushroom
- Cactus
- Pumpkin
- Melon

Or, to be more compact:

- All flowers and mushrooms
- Pumpkins, melons, and cactus
- Sand, gravel and clay
- Dirt, grass, podzol, and mycelium
- TNT