# Most of my house went missing and I don't know why

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was playing singleplayer vanilla 1.14, and I went to a spawner near my house to grind out some XP. When I went back to my house, most of it was missing.
Most of the doors, wood, and stone blocks had just disappeared. It wasn't a clear cut like when loading a chunk goes wrong. Some of the blocks of the base and the roof were still there, but most of the second floor was gone. Things like beds, furnaces, and stuff like that, were still there floating in the air.

I'm not sure if this information helps, but the dogs from the house ran to me while I was at the spawner.

Does anyone know how this is possible?

Comment: What was the house made of, and did you have a fireplace?

Comment: I might also be useful to post an image of your house, and how far away from the spawn chunks is your house? (coordinates of both spawn and your house can help determine if the chunks were loaded or not)

Comment: possibly duplicate of [part of my house is inexplicably gone](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/352473/part-of-my-house-is-inexplicably-gone).

Comment: Typically this can be a result of being struck by lightning but it's hard to tell.  Pro-tip: If I'm building a wooden house, I usually build in the desert where it doesn't rain.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a server, sometimes creepers blow up weirdly and I come on to find portions of my house blown up. It could be that.

Answer (score -1):

A creeper could have blown it up or if you spawned the wither it might have been the withered lightning.